# How to reverse proxy a site which use ssl by nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse

For example:
I want to use a domain reverse proxy https://tw.godaddy.com, is this possible?
My config does not work.

```
        location ~ /
    {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass https://tw.godaddy.com;
            proxy_set_header Host "tw.godaddy.com";
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
            proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
            #more_clear_headers "X-Frame-Options";
            sub_filter_once off;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It is possible.

Requirements:

- Compiled with  `--with-stream`
- Compiled with  `--with-stream_ssl_module`

You can check that with `nginx -V`

Configuration example:

```
stream {

    upstream backend {
        server backend1.example.com:12345;
        server backend2.example.com:12345;
        server backend3.example.com:12345;
   }

    server {
        listen     12345;
        proxy_pass backend;
        proxy_ssl  on;

        proxy_ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/nginxb.crt;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/nginxb.key;
        proxy_ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        proxy_ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/trusted_ca_cert.crt;

        proxy_ssl_verify        on;
        proxy_ssl_verify_depth  2;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    }
}
```

**Explaination:**

Turn on ssl backend:

```
proxy_ssl  on;
```

Specify the path to the SSL client certificate required by the `upstream` server and the certificate’s private key:

```
proxy_ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/nginxb.crt;
proxy_ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/nginxb.key;
```

These client key/certificates are your certificates to start ssl session to backend. you can create self signed via:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/nginxb.key -out /etc/nginx/nginxb.crt
```

If backend is selfsigned too turn off `proxy_ssl_verify` and remove ssl depth.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you are my hero, I will try it. But how could I get backend.crt backend.key trusted_ca_cert.crt?

Comment: @Farhad Farahi is the 2x certs still actually needed if the upstream servers provide their own? When operating within the stream block, is it acting as a pass thru?

Comment: @Chris: its not pass through, if you are using ssl for clients (nginx reverse proxy has ssl verb),nginx will decrypt ssl session, encrypt it again and sends it to the backend. To use pass through, you need to use `stream` block.

Comment: Ah right gotcha, so the nginx reverse proxy always needs its own cert essentially. thanks