# NGINX Reverse Proxy HTTPS

Tags: nginx, apache2

I have two websites hosted on apache2, 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2 (both on port 44443 ssl) respectively.

The point is to have round robin type load balancing with reverse proxy working, so I would type www.reverserobin.local:8888 and it would forward me to https on those websites (backend).
And I have nginx with this configuration.
It is successfully switching between my websites, but the problem is that even tho the apache2 sites are in https and I get forwarded to them in http. Note that it is supposed to receive requests on 8888 and forward to 44443

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:44443;
    server 127.0.0.2:44443;
}

server {
    listen 8888;
    server_name www.reverserobin.local reverserobin.local 
    location / { 
         proxy_pass https://servers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reverse proxy a site which use ssl by nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745961/how-to-reverse-proxy-a-site-which-use-ssl-by-nginx)

Comment: Listen directive should have *ssl* parameter in order to serve encrypted request back to client. It is also recommended to explicitly set a protocol to backend via header _proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;_